# Tcl how to replace data from input

Tags: replace, tcl

I have a txt file

```
#process #AA_version       #BB_version
   a11      Aa/10.10-d87_1    Bb/10.57-d21_1
   a15      Aa/10.15-d37_1    Bb/10.57-d28_1
   a23      Aa/10.20-d51_1    Bb/10.57-d29_3
```

and I want to replace the version I have input

This is my code

```
set fp [open tool_version r]
set process [gets stdin]

while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
  if (regexp $process $line) {
  dict set process1 Aa: [lindex $line 1]
  dict set process1 Bb: [lindex $line 2]
puts "Aa: [lindex $line 1]"
puts "Bb: [lindex $line 2]"
set tool [gets stdin]
if ("$tool"=="Aa")
set new_version [gets stdin]
puts "Aa version : $new_version"
lset [lindex $line1] {} $new_version
  }
}
close $fp
```

but it can't read [lindex $line1] as a variable
or I need to use regsub command?
Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `[lindex $line 1]`, with a space?

Comment: You're assuming each line of the file is a valid list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
switch -- $tool {
    {Aa} {lset line 1 $new_version}
    {Bb} {lset line 2 $new_version}
}
```

Read the docs for `lset`:

> `lset varName ?index ...? newValue`

The first argument is a **variable name**